# Recursive prototype inheritance in nodejs / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, prototype

In my nodejs program, i have a module called person and it has a prototype object(about) which also has its child method (describe). I am trying to access objects properties but i am getting undefined.

Could someone correct my understanding? what i am doing wrong here?

## index.js

```
var Person = require("./person");
var sam = new Person({name:"Sam",age:23})
sam.about.describe();
```

## person.js

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var person = function(options) {
        if (options && options.name) this.name = options.name;
        if (options && options.age) this.age = options.age;
    }
    person.prototype.about = {
        describe : function(){
            console.log("I am",this.name,"and",this.age,"years old");
        }
    }
    return person;
})();
```

Expected output: "I am Sam and 23 years old"
Actual output: "I am undefined and undefined years old"

Comment: Thats because `this` is pointing to `about` and not `person`. Also having object in prototype can have side effect

Comment: What is recursive here?

Comment: @torazaburo.. sorry it is not actually recursive.. will amend..

Comment: What node version are you targeting? If you are fine with ES6, you could probably use arrow function, which does not have its own context.

Comment: Never mind, I just tested it, its not working either...

Comment: @MartinAdámek I am using latest v7.8.0

Comment: See my answer how to achieve that API you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, `this` in your example refers to the about object, not the person instance itself.

One way to have the API you want, is to create that `about` namespace within the constructor, and use `bind` to set correct context to the `describe` handler.

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var person = function(options) {
        if (options && options.name) this.name = options.name;
        if (options && options.age) this.age = options.age;
        this.about = {
            describe: function () {
                console.log("I am",this.name,"and",this.age,"years old");
            }.bind(this)
        };
    }

    return person;
})();
```

This way you can simply call

```
var Person = require("./person");
var sam = new Person({name:"Sam",age:23})
sam.about.describe();

>>> I am Sam and 23 years old
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `this` refers to the direct parent of `describe`, which is `about`:

```
person.prototype.about = {
        describe : function() {
            console.log("I am",this.name,"and",this.age,"years old");
        }
}
```

You'd need a weak reference to the main `Person` object passed to the `about` namespace for example, and use it in place of `this`. But I don't like it that way, it is circumvoluted, feels wrong and looks smelly.

Instead, let's just aknowledge the fact that it's a completely new functionality package added to the Person object and let's make a helper for it:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var PersonHelper = function(person) {
        this.person = person;
        describePerson: function() {
            console.log("I am",this.person.name,"and",this.person.age,"years old");
        }
        /* more methods */
    }
    return PersonHelper;
})();
```

So you could then do:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var person = function(options) {
        if (options && options.name) this.name = options.name;
        if (options && options.age) this.age = options.age;
    }
    return person;
})();


var Person = require("./person");
var PersonHelper = require("./personHelper");
var sam = new Person({name:"Sam",age:23})
var helper = new PersonHelper(person);
helper.describePerson();
```

Comment: like passing sam via describe method ? sam.about.describe(sam); and then describe : function(user){
            console.log("I am",user.name,"and",user.age,"years old");
        }

Comment: yeah that would work, but it's a bit ugly. Maybe you'd be better off using a PersonHelper object all together, that would embed functions like describe etc. Let me put that on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be able to use `sam.about.describe`, with an `about` "namespace" containing methods, then one approach is

```
Object.defineProperty(person.prototype, 'about', {
  get() { 
    return { 
      describe: () => console.log("I am", this.name, "and", this.age, "years old"); 
    };
  }
})
```

This works because the context within `get` is that of the `Person` instance, and the arrow function will thus refer to it properly.

Comment: But as per my requirement, i need "about" namespace which contains multiple functions like "describe"